# How to read stream from WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have created a WCF service to stream files(download). Code for the service is below

```
public Stream GetCoverScan(List<string> productIDs)
{
    FileStream stream = new FileStream("", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    return stream;
}
```

Can some one tell me how do i consume this on the client side. I have already created a proxy on client and i can see the method by creating an object of the service, but how do i read the stream.

Please advise

Configuration

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="StreamedHttp" transferMode="StreamedResponse"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="Streaming.Service1"
                 behaviorConfiguration="Streaming.Service1Behavior">
            <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="StreamedHttp"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Streaming.IService1">
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Streaming.Service1Behavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(string name);

    [OperationContract]
    System.IO.Stream GetCoverScan(List<string> productIDs);
}
```

bindings

```
</bindings>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the signature of the generated proxy method is?

Comment: well that the confusing thing  when i see the signature of the proxy method that is when i do "obj.GetCoverScan" (obj is the object of my service) i can see that its return type is byte array and it takes string array as parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [configure streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) on the binding you use. Streaming is supported for `BasicHttpBinding`, `NetTcpBinding`, and `NetNamedPipeBinding`. So if you have a `BasicHttpBinding`, your configuration should look like this:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HttpStreaming" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
             transferMode="StreamedResponse"/>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

I use `StreamedResponse` here because you only have a response that should be a stream, not a request.

How you read the stream itself depends on what's in it. Suppose you send a text file over a stream, you can use a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx):

```
var reader = new StreamReader(service.GetCoverScan(...));
string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

If you send an xml file, you can read it through [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(service.GetCoverScan(...));
```

So it really depends on what you're sending over the wire.

Comment: Roanld, thanks for the reply, yeah i have already done that. 
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="StreamedHttp" transferMode="StreamedResponse" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

Comment: ronald, could you please advise me on how do i get the stream at client side? Darin (above) advised on using the below

byte[] result = proxy.GetCoverScan(productIDs);
File.WriteAllBytes("foo.dat", result);

But using this will buffer the response i guess but i want to stream. Its a little confusing please help
thanks

Comment: The generated client proxy should have a signature that returns a Stream, **not** a byte array. I just tested this myself. So something goes wrong while generating the client. Can you add your configuration to your question?

Comment: Ronald, i have added the configuration in the question. Please advise

Comment: Can you also add your bindings (at least the basicHttpBinding)?

Comment: Sorry i haven't defined any binding outside of the config file.

Comment: Please find the binding below

<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="StreamedHttp" transferMode="StreamedResponse" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

Comment: i have added the bindings above in the question as well but for some reason they are not appearing. I can see them when i edit my question

Comment: it is there in the config file but for some reason this website is not displaying it

Comment: Strange. I use the same configuration you have and my client returns a stream and not a byte array. How do you generate the client? Via svcutil or via Add Service Reference in Visual Studio?

Comment: i do it through "add web reference"

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use? 'Add web reference' does not generate a WCF client. Before WCF you had ASMX web services that supported only a small part of the SOAP stack. Streaming is not supported for these types of clients.

Comment: Do you not have a 'Add Service Reference' option somewhere? I'm using VS2010 myself. I suppose you use VS2008?

Comment: i think the way i m creating the proxy is incorrect  I am doing add web reference whereas i should be doing add service reference

Comment: Precisely :) You should use 'Add Service Reference'.

Comment: Ronald, I used add service reference and i can now see it returns a stream. I can't thank you enough. Appreciate your patience.

One small lil thing now that i have the stream as my return type how do i read from it.

Comment: Your welcome :) I added some info to my answer that tells you how to read from a stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you mention

`response.ContentType = "text/xml"`

*just before* returning stream, the receiving application can know the type of the stream thus can invoke standard way of stream as a reference.