# System.OutOfMemoryException .NET 4.8 WPF App

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, reflection

I'm working on a WPF (WCF architecture) app. This app has 2 main solutions, the client(front end) and the controller(back end),  the way the client communicates with the back end is through reflective calls, in essences it builds up a XML doc containing info like the method to execute, the namespace that the method is in and method args etc...

So this specific method is to upload documents. It works perfectly until the file is > 1GB in size. The error occurs when the client builds up the XML doc for the reflective call.

We add to the XML doc like this:

```
result.Add(new XElement(itemProperty.Name, new XCData(data)));
```

In this case the itemProperty.Name is the method name and the XCData is the method args.
So the doc to upload will obvisolsy be the arguments, we receive it in a byte[]. And we need to pass it to the XCData constructor as a string, so the following is used:

```
string data= Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])value)
```

Note that this works with smaller files but with the 1GB file a 'System.OutOfMemoryException' exception is thrown when trying to convert the byte[] to base64String.

I have tried reading the array in chunks, but when calling the stringBuilder.ToString(), the same exception is thrown...

```
 public static string HandleBigByteArray(byte[] arr)
        {
            try
            {
                
                #region approach 2
                int chunkSize = 104857600;//100MB
                StringBuilder b64StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                int offset = 0;

                while (offset < arr.Length)
                {
                    int remainingBytes = arr.Length - offset;
                    int bytesToEncode = Math.Min(chunkSize, remainingBytes);
                    string base64Chunk = Convert.ToBase64String(arr, offset, bytesToEncode);
                    b64StringBuilder.Append(base64Chunk);
                    offset += bytesToEncode;
                }


                return b64StringBuilder.ToString();
                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I have no idea what to do or how to further debug/approach this..

Comment: The only way of parsing a huge XML file in Net is to use XmlReader.  See my solution at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607180/parse-big-xml-file-using-xmlreader

Comment: `XmlSerializer` (and LINQ to XML) will throw out-of-memory exceptions if your text values exceed the effective [maximum string length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/140468) on your platform.  When that happens I agree with @jdweng you will need to write and read your XML to/from some temp file (or [`RecyclableMemoryStream`](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream)) using `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`.

Comment: To read a huge Base94-encoded XML text value incrementally, see [XmlReader - How to read very long string in element without System.OutOfMemoryException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54126687/3744182).  When writing Base64 in chunks, [`XmlWriter.WriteBase64()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writebase64) can be called repeatedly for each chunk.

Comment: @Kyle: Does using the `CryptoStream` class work for you?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525533/is-there-a-base64stream-for-net

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the links i'll check everything out, but parsing the XML is not the issue. Not sure if it will become one. But the exception is thrown when the byte array calls .ToBase64String(), the bytes = 1GB, surely a string can hold more than that..?

Comment: @Kyle - basically no, it can't.  The [`String.Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length?view=net-7.0) property is an **`Int32`** so the max theoretical length is 2^31 characters = 4GB bytes.  But you are actually limited to 2GB bytes unless you set [`gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59730510).  See [What is the maximum possible length of a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/140468).

Comment: *parsing the XML is not the issue* -- maybe not yet but unless you are using `XmlReader` to read it manually I suspect your Base64-encoded `byte []` array sizes are within a factor of roughly 2 to 4 of becoming too large to deserialize.  I recommend you rethink your design and consider streaming solutions.

Comment: If you cannot rethink your design, I can imagine some kludges to work around the max string length on the client side -- but you will still be using enormous amounts of RAM unnecessarily.  Would those kluges be useful?

Comment: @dbc, in a normal 'programming standard' is it acceptable to limit the user to a certain file size? Because I must admit the 1Gb file is excessive... I tried inspecting the diagnostic tools(when using the method handlebigByteArray in my question) VS debugger offers, and found 21 instances of the stringBuilder class holding MORE than 2GB in memory. not sure if this is helpful or not, I could also be wrong since I'm not 100% confident in reading the data provided by the diagnostic tools..

Comment: @Kyle - *in a normal 'programming standard' is it acceptable to limit the user to a certain file size?* -- that's not a programming question, that's a business requirements question.  If your business needs your app to support files that large, you will need to design your client + server to support it.  But supporting upload of files that large can cost your business money (e.g. server storage costs, bandwidth costs, support costs, etc. etc.) which is why for business reasons many upload apps do enforce file size limits.

Comment: It's certainly possible to support upload of files larger than 2GB using asp.net, see [Exceeding the 2GB file upload limitation in IIS 7.5 and .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16738849).  However you can't do it using a single contiguous Base64 string embedded in some XML container that is entirely loaded into RAM.

Comment: And of course allowing uploaded of truly unlimited file sizes puts you at risk of denial of service attacks.  It's certainly a *normal 'programming standard'* to prevent DOS attacks.

Comment: *I ... found 21 instances of the stringBuilder class holding MORE than 2GB in memory.* -- internally `StringBuilder` uses a linked list of chunks of limited size so it can hold more than 2GB bytes.  But if you check the [reference source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Text/StringBuilder.cs#L78) you will see that `StringBuilder` has an `int m_MaxCapacity` field which is set to `m_MaxCapacity = int.MaxValue;` by default, so in fact it you cannot have a `StringBuilder` holding more than 4GM of memory.

Comment: @Kyle - wrapping things up, do you need the kludge for adding arbitrarily large sequences of bytes to an `XElement` value?

Comment: @dbc, elaborate on what you mean with a kludge?

Comment: I think that the reason may be that the byte array is split into multiple smaller fragments, but each fragment still takes up a lot of memory space, resulting in memory fragmentation. You can free up the memory in each loop. You can also better divide the size of each piece.

Comment: @Kyle - From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge) -- *A kludge or kluge is a workaround or quick-and-dirty solution that is clumsy, inelegant, inefficient, difficult to extend and hard to maintain.*  See my answer to see what I mean,

Comment: I dont get it.. This is the total string max length > 2 147 483 647
this is the lenght of my string > 1 239 565 472

Comment: @Kyle - as explained in [What is the maximum possible length of a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/140468/3744182) the longest string you can actually allocate on a 64 bit system will be less than `int.MaxValue`, most likely `1,073,741,823` characters.

Comment: @dbc , ok. My sprint on this project has ended. I will have a look at this issue again in 1 weeks time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem here is that, in constructing your Base64 string, when you do `b64StringBuilder.ToString()` you are trying to exceed the **maximum possible .NET string length** on your system, which is, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/140749/3744182) by HitScan to *[What is the maximum possible length of a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/140468/3744182)*, at most `int.MaxValue / 2` characters on a 64-bit system.

To break that down, the largest contiguous memory block you can allocate on .NET Framework is `int.MaxValue` bytes, or 2GB.  A `char` takes 2 bytes, and Base64 encoding inflates the character count by 33%, so the maximum size byte array you could encode is around 3/4 GB -- which is exactly what you are seeing.

(Note that if you set [`gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element), you will be able to allocate arrays of up to 4GB in memory, so multiply the above calculation by a factor of 2 if you do.)

**To solve this particular problem**, rather than creating a single `XCData` containing the entire Base64 contents of the `byte []` array, you could create a sequence of `XText` containing partial chunks of bounded size and add them all to the `itemProperty.Name` element.  They will be formatted as a single contiguous text value when written to XML.

To do this, first introduce the following extension methods:

```
public static partial class XmlExtensions
{
    const int DefaultChunkLength = 8000;
    const int Base64BytesPerChunk = 3; // Base64 encodes 3 bytes to 4 characters.
    
    public static IEnumerable<XText> ToBase64XTextChunks(this Stream stream, int chunkLength = DefaultChunkLength)
    {
        return stream.ToBase64StringChunks(chunkLength).Select(s => new XText(s));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<XText> ToBase64XTextChunks(this IEnumerable<byte []> chunks, int chunkLength = DefaultChunkLength)
    {
        return chunks.Select(b => new ArraySegment<byte>(b)).ToBase64XTextChunks(chunkLength);
    }

    // In .NET Core I would use Memory<T> and/or ReadOnlyMemory<T> instead of ArraySegment<T>.

    public static IEnumerable<XText> ToBase64XTextChunks(this IEnumerable<ArraySegment<byte>> chunks, int chunkLength = DefaultChunkLength)
    {
        return chunks.ToBase64StringChunks(chunkLength).Select(s => new XText(s));
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<string> ToBase64StringChunks(this Stream stream, int chunkLength = DefaultChunkLength)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
        if (chunkLength < 1 || chunkLength > int.MaxValue / Base64BytesPerChunk)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("chunkLength < 1 || chunkLength > int.MaxValue / Base64BytesPerChunk");
        var buffer = new byte[Math.Max(300, Base64BytesPerChunk * DefaultChunkLength)];
        return ToBase64StringChunksEnumerator(stream.ReadAllByteChunks(buffer), chunkLength);
    }
    
    internal static IEnumerable<string> ToBase64StringChunks(this IEnumerable<ArraySegment<byte>> chunks, int chunkLength = DefaultChunkLength)
    {
        if (chunks == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("chunks");
        if (chunkLength < 1 || chunkLength > int.MaxValue / 3)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("chunkLength < 1 || chunkLength > int.MaxValue / 3");
        return ToBase64StringChunksEnumerator(chunks, chunkLength);
    }
    
    static IEnumerable<string> ToBase64StringChunksEnumerator(this IEnumerable<ArraySegment<byte>> chunks, int chunkLength)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[Base64BytesPerChunk*chunkLength];
        foreach (var chunk in chunks.ToFixedSizedChunks(buffer))
        {
            yield return Convert.ToBase64String(chunk.Array, chunk.Offset, chunk.Count);
        }
    }
    
    internal static IEnumerable<ArraySegment<byte>> ReadAllByteChunks(this Stream stream, byte [] buffer)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
        if (buffer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
        if (buffer.Length < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("buffer.Length < 1");
        return ReadAllByteChunksEnumerator(stream, buffer);
    }

    static IEnumerable<ArraySegment<byte>> ReadAllByteChunksEnumerator(Stream stream, byte [] buffer)
    {
        int nRead;
        while ((nRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            yield return new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, nRead);
    }
}

public static partial class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ArraySegment<T>> ToFixedSizedChunks<T>(this IEnumerable<ArraySegment<T>> chunks, T [] buffer)
    {
        if (chunks == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("chunks");
        if (buffer.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("buffer.Length == 0");
        return ToFixedSizedChunksEnumerator(chunks, buffer);
    }
    
    static IEnumerable<ArraySegment<T>> ToFixedSizedChunksEnumerator<T>(IEnumerable<ArraySegment<T>> chunks, T [] buffer) 
    {
        int bufferIndex = 0;
        bool anyRead = false, anyReturned = false;
        foreach (var chunk in chunks)
        {
            anyRead = true;
            int chunkIndex = 0;
            while (chunkIndex < chunk.Count)
            {
                int toCopy = Math.Min(buffer.Length - bufferIndex, chunk.Count - chunkIndex);
                if (toCopy > 0)
                {
                    chunk.CopyTo(chunkIndex, buffer, bufferIndex, toCopy);
                    bufferIndex += toCopy;
                    if (bufferIndex == buffer.Length)
                    {
                        yield return new ArraySegment<T>(buffer, 0, bufferIndex);
                        bufferIndex = 0;
                        anyReturned = true;
                    }
                }
                chunkIndex += toCopy;
            }
        }
        // If passed an enumerable of empty chunks we should still return one empty chunk.  But if there were no chunks at all, return nothing.
        if (bufferIndex > 0 || (anyRead && !anyReturned))
            yield return new ArraySegment<T>(buffer, 0, bufferIndex);
    }
    
    public static void CopyTo<T>(this ArraySegment<T> from, int fromIndex, T [] destination, int destinationIndex, int count)
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(from.Array, checked(from.Offset + fromIndex), destination, destinationIndex, count);
    }
}
```

And now, assuming your `byte[] arr` value was actually read from a file `fileName`, you can do:

```
var result = new XElement("root");

var e = new XElement(itemProperty.Name);
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{
    foreach (var text in stream.ToBase64XTextChunks())
        e.Add(text);
}
result.Add(e);
```

The extension method `stream.ToBase64XTextChunks()` reads the stream in chunks and encodes in chunks so you never hit the maximum array size or the maximum string length.

But if you already have your huge `byte [] arr` array in memory, you can do:

```
    foreach (var text in new [] { arr }.ToBase64XTextChunks())
        e.Add(text);
```

Notes

- I recommend, for performance reasons, keeping your buffer and string allocations smaller than 80,000 bytes so that they don't go on the [large object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8951836).
- In .NET Core I would use `Memory<T>` and `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` instead of the older `ArraySegment<T>`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Muiwk).

That being said, **you are very close to hitting other memory limits as well**, including:

- The maximum `byte []` array size, which is `int.MaxValue`, i.e. 2 GB.

  Setting `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` does not increase this limit.  `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` only increases the amount of **memory** an array can hold.  The **length** is still limited to `int.MaxValue`.

  This limit will be a problem on both the client and server sides.
- The maximum number of characters that can be held by a `StringBuilder`, which can be seen from the [reference source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Text/StringBuilder.cs#L78) to be `int.MaxValue`.
- Your server's total available virtual memory.  Your current design does not seem to limit upload sizes **at all**.  That appears to make your server vulnerable to denial-of-service attacks where the attacker continues to upload data until your server runs out of memory.

  And if you have a large number of clients that upload huge chunks of data at the same time, you server will again run out of memory even if none of the clients is attempting a DOS attack.
- Your client's available virtual memory.  If your clients are running in resource-restricted environments (such as smartphones) huge memory allocations may not be possible.

I would suggest that you rethink your design of allowing arbitrarily large file uploads, and buffering them in memory on both the client and server sides.  Even if you decide that, for business reasons, you need to support upload of files larger than 1 or 2 GB, I recommend that you adopt a **streaming** solution where the contents are written and read using `XmlWriter` and `XmlReader` without ever loading the entire contents into memory.  To get started, see

- [Exceeding the 2GB file upload limitation in IIS 7.5 and .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16738849).
- [How to: Enable Streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-enable-streaming).
- [How to read stream from WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3590276).
- [How to perform streaming transform of large XML documents (LINQ to XML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/perform-streaming-transform-large-xml-documents).
- [XmlReader - How to read very long string in element without System.OutOfMemoryException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54126687/3744182).
- [Parse Big XML file using XMLReader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61607180/3744182).